How is sitecore experience analytics Dashboard filters coming?
I don't have much experience in Sitecore experience analytics setup. Currently, the problem I am facing is that there are various unwanted filters coming in experience analytics dashboard.

How can i remove these unwanted filters ? I have already check if any filters available in /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Filters folder, but looks empty, any suggestions or help are appreciated
Thanks!


If you want to prevent some of the subsites to be displayed in this filter, try using this approach.
All what you need to do is to go to the site definition configuration you have and add the following attribute to the sites that you want to stop collecting analytics data on:
enableTracking="false"

If you want to know more about the Experience Analytics filter, you can refer to this document.
http://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.com/2017/08/sitecore-experience-analytics-dive-deep.html
Hope this will work for you.

Filter inside Sitecore Experience Analytics dashboard is populated from the SiteNames table inside the Reporting dashboard.
You can find the list of site names by running the below query on SiteNames table.
SELECT TOP (1000) [SiteNameId]
      ,[SiteName]
  FROM [ReportingDatabase].[dbo].[SiteNames]

This returns the output as below.

You can remove the unwanted site from this list and restart the application pool after that.
Also make sure once you delete the sites from the above table, enabletracking attribute is set to false for each of those site definition.
<sites>
   <site name="{{SiteName}}" enableTracking="false"/>
</sites>

This ensures tracking from those sites are not stored and do not appear on the filter again.
Hope this helps!!!
